# How can I change a RecyclerView list item property if the conditional comes from an other class?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, background-color

I would like to create a TodoList application and I would like to adjust some property of current item in RecyclerView list.
The user can choose a due date and one method check always how many days are remain to that. and I would like to change the background of the remain day is 0 or less.

Here is the Main code what handle the data what the user gives:

```
package com.example.recycleviewapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

public class ToDoList extends AppCompatActivity implements MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener, View.OnClickListener {
    MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    public Button btn;
    public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor myEdit;
    private ArrayList<String> items;
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shoppinglist);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ToDoList", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        myEdit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        StartDisplay();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this,items);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ToDoList", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String item_click =adapter.getItem(position);
        String[] itemarray = item_click.split(" ",0);
        myEdit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        myEdit.remove(itemarray[0]);
        myEdit.commit();
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        items.remove(item_click);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent NewTLItem = new Intent(ToDoList.this, NewTLItem.class);
        startActivity(NewTLItem);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        StartDisplay();
    }
    public void StartDisplay()
    {
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ToDoList", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Map<String, ?> allEntries = sharedPreferences.getAll();
        items.clear();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet())
        {
            String [] item_total = entry.getValue().toString().split(";");
            long remain_days = DateCalc(item_total[0]);
            items.add(entry.getKey() + " " + item_total[0] + "Remaining days: " + String.valueOf(remain_days) );
        }
    }
    
    public long DateCalc(String startdate)
    {
        Date system_date, due_date;
        long diff_date = 0;
        String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        SimpleDateFormat dates = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        try {
            system_date = dates.parse(currentDate);
            due_date = dates.parse(String.format(startdate, "dd-MM-yyyy"));
            diff_date = (due_date.getTime()-system_date.getTime())/86400000;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return diff_date;
    }
}
```

and here is my RecyclerView adapter class:

```
package com.example.recycleviewapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.List;

public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    
    MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String meta_data = mData.get(position);
        if (meta_data.contains("Remaining days: 2")) holder.myTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF003B"));
        holder.myTextView.setText(meta_data);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView myTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAnimalName);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
        if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    String getItem(int id) {return mData.get(id);
    }
    
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }


}
```

I can change the background of the item if the conditional contained by the item, for example the TextView contains the number of the remain day like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String meta_data = mData.get(position);
    if (meta_data.contains("Remaining days: 2")) holder.myTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF003B"));
    holder.myTextView.setText(meta_data);
}
```

but I would not like to show the number of the remaining days, only evaluate the conditional and change the background or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Make `List<String> mData` public or write a setter.
After you make changes on the items array in the activity, call functions below.

```
adapter.mData = items;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but unfortunatelly I dont know how to helps it in my problem. Because I would like to reach the "holder.myTextView.setBackgroundColor()" method from my Main class. Somehow like this: 
if(remain_days <=0)
{
//something code here to reach holder.myTextView.setBackgroundColor() method
}
and I would like to put this conditional evaluate in my Main class into StartDisplay() function.